Sharing output between reusable action and caller workflow in github action
I have reusable workflow in which I am declaring some github action outputs.
# .github/actions/tests/action.yml
name: ""
description: "Runs Docker tests"
inputs:
  go-version:
    description: "Version of Go to set up"
    required: true
outputs:
  test_status:
    description: "The result of the tests: success or failure"

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name: Set up Go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v3
      with:
        go-version: ${{ inputs.go-version }}

    - name: Run tests
      id: run_tests
      run: |
        set +e
        output=$(go test -v ./... -tags=run_check)
        set -e
        echo $output
        if echo "$output" | grep -q "FAIL"; then
          echo "test_status=failure" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          exit 1
        else

          echo "test_status=success" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
        fi
      working-directory: test
      shell: bash

And I am calling this action in another repo
Caller workflow:
      - name: Run post build tests
        id: post_buid_tests
        uses: <owner>/<repo>/.github/actions/tests@main 
        with:
          go-version: '1.23'

Now when I am trying to access this output it it returns nothing
      - name: Post Node image
        if: ${{ steps.post_buid_tests.outputs.test_status == 'success' }}
        run: | 
          echo "Test Status: Successful"

steps.post_buid_tests.outputs.test_status this returns nothing.. please note that reusable action and caller workflow are in diff repositories.
I tried using github_output, but it didn't work, whereas github_env works fine. Does this mean we can't share variables between repositories in GitHub Actions?

What you have is a composite action, which isn't the same as a reusable workflow; see Avoiding Duplication in the docs for details.
You're missing setting the value in your action metadata: it has to look like
outputs:
  test_status:
    description: "The result of the tests: success or failure"
    value: ${{ steps.run_tests.outputs.test_status }}

